# ActionBar with icon & title

Tags: java, android

I have an existing app which ActionBar. The actionbar had a back button (where revelant), icon, title  aligned on left and options menu on the right. I added the AppCompat library to the project recently. Now the icon is gone. The back, title & options show up alright.

So I set out to create a toolbar and included it to the layouts. The problem is there are many screens which has started crashing because I didnt include the toolbar. Plus, getSupportActionBar is returning null if NoActionBar theme is added.

Can there be a simple way to retain the old actionbar (without adding toolbar)?

Code

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if(actionBar != null) {
      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      if (toolbar != null)
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      actionBar.setTitle("Scan Code");
 }
```

Toolbar layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:navigationIcon="@drawable/app_icon">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Style

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="icon">@mipmap/app_icon</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please add logcat error

Comment: and please check you extend AppComptActivity and menifest style theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to replace the action bar with toolbar in all activities I would override setContentView() method in BaseActivity. It looks like this:

```
    @Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.toolbarContainer);
    if (view != null) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        setTitle(getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: this seemed a neater implementation as all the views have setContentView which can be overridden to add custom settings.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple. You need a custom toolbar for a particular screen. You have made the apptheme = `AppTheme.NoActionBar`. This means that all your screens wont have a toolbar. 
First change your appthem to default as it was.

```
<style name="AppStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="icon">@mipmap/app_icon</item>
</style>
```

If you want to change the toolbar just for one screen u can add a custom style like same as your Apptheme.

```
<style name="CustomStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="icon">@mipmap/app_icon</item>
</style>
```

And add this style when you are declaring this activity in your manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/CustomStyle"
    android:name=".MyActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- remove the `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`
- use `setTitle` 、`setNavigationIcon` in `Toolbar`

Try this .

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
// App Logo
toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
// Title
toolbar.setTitle("My Title");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
// Navigation Icon
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this remove **`android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`**

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ar_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

apply this theme to your activity

```
<style name="AccountSetting" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

 </style>
```